# Laravel error when running npm run dev command

Tags: laravel, vue.js

When I run npm run dev in the terminal I get the following message:

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [vue-loader] vue-template-compiler must be installed as a peer dependency, or a compatible compiler implementation must be passed via options.
    at loadTemplateCompiler (/portal/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js:21:11)
    at Object.module.exports (
(/portal/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js:65:35)
 @ ./resources/js/app.js 19:35-79
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

Can anyone tell me what this error means and how do I fix it?

I tried to run this command in the terminal, but I am still getting the error.

The command: npm i -D vue-template-compiler

I have also tried to reinstall all of my dependencies, but that didnt work either.

Comment: Check this [github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/560#issuecomment-284260775): `vue` and `vue-template-compiler` should be at the same version

Comment: Which laravel version? Are you using laravel mix or vue-cli?

Comment: Laravel version 5.7.19. I am using laravel mix.

Comment: "vue": "^2.5.17", "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.22", "vue-loader": "^15.5.1". That is in my package.json file

Comment: Do you know how to update both to the same version?

Comment: In your package.json, remove `^` from the vue version to install exact version. Put both `vue` and `vue-template-compiler` to same version, for example `2.5.22`. For any package on the npm registry, you can see the versions of the package on the [package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-template-compiler) - there is sub-tab `N versions`

Comment: Or you can run this command in terminal: `npm view vue versions`